# Is there a module like Perl's LWP for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, perl, rubygems

In Perl there is an [LWP module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP):

> The libwww-perl collection is a set of Perl modules which provides a simple and consistent application programming interface (API) to the World-Wide Web. The main focus of the library is to provide classes and functions that allow you to write WWW clients. The library also contain modules that are of more general use and even classes that help you implement simple HTTP servers.

Is there a similar module (gem) for Ruby?

**Update**

Here is an example of a function I have made that extracts URL's from a specific website.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::TreeBuilder 3;
use HTML::TokeParser;

sub get_gallery_urls {
    my $url = shift;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
    $ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");

    my $req = new HTTP::Request 'GET' => "$url";
    $req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');

    # send request
    $response_u = $ua->request($req);

    die "Error: ", $response_u->status_line unless $response_u->is_success;

    my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
    $root->parse($response_u->content);

    my @gu = $root->find_by_attribute("id", "thumbnails");

    my %urls = ();

    foreach my $g (@gu) {
        my @as = $g->find_by_tag_name('a');

        foreach $a (@as) {
            my $u = $a->attr("href");

            if ($u =~ /^\//) {
                $urls{"http://example.com"."$u"} = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return %urls;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what made you think `LWP` is for parsing HTML.

Comment: I have used it to extract all sorts of things from HTML, and also fill out forms online, submit them, and navigate around on the website with `LWP`.

Comment: Wow, that would have been a lot simpler using WWW::Mechanize in Perl (or Ruby).

Comment: It's TreeBuilder that's the parser. The ruby equivalent is Nokogiri.

Comment: Always `use strict` and `use warnings` until you know **exactly** why it is recommended. If you did you would find `for $a (@AS){...}` was reporting an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest match is probably [httpclient](http://rubygems.org/gems/httpclient), which aims to be the equivalent of LWP. However, depending on what you plan to do, there may be better options. If you plan to follow links, fill out forms, etc. in order to scrape web content, you can use [Mechanize](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) which is similar to the perl module by the same name. There are also more Ruby-specific gems, such as the excellent [Rest-client](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) and [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) (my personal favorite). See the [HTTP Clients category of Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) for a larger list.

**Update**: Here's an example of how to find all links on a page in Mechanize (Ruby, but it would be similar in Perl):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://example.com/')

page.links.each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```

P.S. As an ex-Perler myself, I used to worry about abandoning the excellent CPAN--would I paint myself into a corner with Ruby? Would I not be able to find an equivalent to a module I rely on? This has turned out not to be a problem at all, and in fact lately has been quite the opposite: Ruby (along with Python) tends to be the first to get client support for new platforms/web services, etc.

Comment: That is exactly the situation I am in. I know Perl, and know a few Perl books by heart. I have written a Web 2.0 website in Perl, but it was not fun and way too hard. So my plan is to solve future problems in Ruby, and just have to accept that it is going to take 20x as long in the beginning.

Comment: Why not learn a decent framework and stack such as Mojolicious on top of Plack/PSGI?  Rapid development, modern, elegant, portable... a great option that builds on your existing Perl prowess.

Comment: @DavidO Reading about Plack it is not clear to me what it exactly simplifies. Do you know of an before/after example?

Comment: Your web framework (Catalyst, Mojolicious, etc) sits on top of Plack.  Plack is designed to abstract away the detail of what type of web-server you're catering to.  You could put Plack on top of Apache, some cloud service, or any number of other webservers (including its own stand-alone server) without changing the app that sits on top of it at all.

Comment: Sandra Schlichting: If it's too hard, then it's a sign you're handling your tool wrong. I don't know anything about your website project, but it's telling you don't know Plack. The code in the question can be replaced w/ `use URI; use Web::Query; my %urls = map { URI->new($_)->abs('http://example.com')->as_string => 1 } wq($url)->find('#thumbnails a')->attr('href');`, short enough for a oneliner. The dilemma is solved by learning more CPAN (so visit [local mongers](http://pm.org) and [events](http://yapceurope.org/events/)), not jumping into a different language which you know even less about.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what your function might look like in ruby.

```
require 'rubygems'
require "mechanize"

def get_gallery_urls url
    ua = Mechanize.new
    ua.user_agent = "Mozilla/8.0"
    urls = {}

    doc = ua.get url
    doc.search("#thumbnails a").each do |a|
        u = a["href"]
        urls["http://example.com#{u}"] = 1 if u =~ /^\//
    end

    urls
end
```

Much nicer :)

Comment: Don't you have to check return values? In my case I need to check `$response_u->is_success` to make sure the page was downloaded successfully before I parse it.

Comment: It will raise an exception if something goes wrong. You can handle it in the function if you want or ignore it with something like: gallery_urls = get_gallery_urls(myurl) rescue nil

Answer (score 3):

I used Perl for years and years, and liked LWP. It was a great tool. However, here's how I'd go about extracting URLs from a page. This isn't spidering a site, but that'd be an easy thing:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

urls = URI.extract(open('http://example.com').read)
puts urls
```

With the resulting output looking like:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
http://www.icann.org/
mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback
```

Writing that as a method:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

def get_gallery_urls(url)
  URI.extract(open(url).read)
end
```

or, closer to the original function while doing it the Ruby-way:

```
def get_gallery_urls(url)
  URI.extract(open(url).read).map{ |u| 
    URI.parse(u).host ? u : URI.join(url, u).to_s
  }
end
```

or, following closer to the original code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

def get_gallery_urls(url)
  Nokogiri::HTML(
    open(url)
  )
    .at('#thumbnails')
    .search('a')
    .map{ |link|
      href = link['href']
      URI.parse(link[href]).host \
        ? href \
        : URI.join(url, href).to_s
    }
end
```

One of the things that attracted me to Ruby is its ability to be readable, while still being concise.

If you want to roll your own TCP/IP-based functions, Ruby's standard Net library is the starting point. By default you get:

```
net/ftp
net/http
net/imap
net/pop
net/smtp
net/telnet
```

with the SSL-based ssh, scp, sftp and others available as gems. Use `gem search net -r | grep ^net-` to see a short list.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an answer for anyone looking at this question and needing to know what are easier/better/different alternatives to general web scraping with Perl compared to using [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) (and even [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-Mechanize)).

Here is a quick selection of web scraping modules on [`CPAN`](https://metacpan.org/):

- [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent)
- [`pQuery`](https://metacpan.org/module/pQuery)
- [`Scrappy`](https://metacpan.org/release/Scrappy)
- [`Web::Magic`](https://metacpan.org/module/Web::Magic)
- [`Web::Scraper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Web::Scraper)
- [`Web::Query`](https://metacpan.org/module/Web::Query)

NB. Above is just in alphabetical order so please choose your favourite poison :)

For most of my recent web scraping I've been using `pQuery`.  You can see there are quite a few [examples of usage on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+pquery).

Below is your `get_gallery_urls` example using `pQuery`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use pQuery;

sub get_gallery_urls {
    my $url = shift;
    my %urls;

    pQuery($url)
        ->find("#thumbnails a")
        ->each( sub {
            my $u = $_->getAttribute('href');
            $urls{'http://example.com' . $u} = 1 if $u =~ /^\//;
        });

    return %urls;
}
```

PS. As Daxim has said in the comments there are plenty of excellent Perl tools for web scraping.  The hardest part is just making a choice of which one to use!