# Can this be made easier with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, perl, mechanize

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274221/is-there-a-module-like-perls-lwp-for-ruby) post I learned that `Mechanize` in Ruby/Perl is easier to use than `HTML::TreeBuilder 3` in that particular example.

Is `Mechanize` superior to `HTML::TokeParser`?

Would the below also have been easier to write in Ruby using `Mechanize`?

```
sub get_img_page_urls {
    my $url = shift;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
    $ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");

    my $req = new HTTP::Request 'GET' => "$url";
    $req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');

    $response_u = $ua->request($req);  # send request

    die "Error: ", $response_u->status_line unless $response_u->is_success;

    my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$response_u->content);

    my %urls = ();

    my $found_thumbnails = 0;
    my $found_thumb = 0;

    while (my $token = $stream->get_token) {

        # <div class="thumb-box" ... >
        if ($token->[0] eq 'S' and $token->[1] eq 'div' and $token->[2]{class} eq 'thumb-box') {
            $found_thumbnails = 1;
        }

        # <div class="thumb" ... >
        if ($token->[0] eq 'S' and $token->[1] eq 'div' and $token->[2]{class} eq 'thumb') {
            $found_thumb = 1;
        }

        #                                          <a ... >
        if ($found_thumbnails and $found_thumb and $token->[0] eq 'S' and $token->[1] eq 'a') {
            $urls{'http://example.com' . "$token->[2]{href}"} = 1;

            # one url have been found. Now start all over.
            $found_thumb = 0;
            $found_thumbnails = 0;
        }

    }

    return %urls;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that you should get in the habit of using true/false instead of 1/0 because 0 in ruby evaluates to true.

Comment: This is nearly identical to your other question. Mechanize is not a parser, so you can't compare it to TokeParser. (But IMHO any modern DOM parser is going to be superior to TokeParser for things like this). And yes it is easier to write in Ruby, whether you use Mechanize or not. (That code can be simpler in Perl too BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize is more than a parser. It adds an emulated browser, which allows you to navigate a site, fill out forms, etc. But it also includes a parser, making web scraping very simple. Here's your method rewritten using ruby Mechanize:

```
def get_img_page_urls(url)
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.user_agent_alias = "Windows Mozilla"
  agent.get(url).search("//div[@class='thumb-box']/div[@class='thumb']/a/@href")
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Anything is better than HTML::TokeParser, speaking about the interface. WWW::Mechanize shines with forms, but it also lacks a declarative way to find certain elements. I'm fond of [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web::Query) and [HTML::Query](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Query) who modeled their interface after jQuery which as far as I know made this sort of programming popular.

The program from the question is shorter as follows. It automatically raises exceptions, so no need for explicit error handling.

```
use URI;
use Web::Query 'wq';

sub get_img_page_urls {
    my ($url) = @_;
    $Web::Query::UserAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/8.0');

    return map {
        URI->new($_)->abs('http://example.com')->as_string   # hash key
        => 1                                                 # hash value
    } wq($url)->find('div.thumb-box div.thumb a')->attr('href');
}
```

Previously posted as comment https://stackoverflow.com/q/8274221#comment-10196381

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you would need to use Mechanize as I think [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) would suffice. I don't know perl so I am not totally sure how the html is laid out in your example but I am assuming it's like this:

```
<div class="thumb-box">
  ...
  <div class="thumb">
    ...
    <a href="http://example.com/img/5.jpg">...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def get_img_page_urls(url)
  urls = []
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com', 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/8.0'))
  doc.css('div.thumb-box div.thumb a').each do |link|
    urls << link.attr("href")
  end

  urls
end
```

Comment: +1 for Ruby+Nokogiri. This could be written even shorter: `Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com')).css('div.thumb-box div.thumb a').map(&:href)`

Comment: Can you please add how to set the custom user-agent string so that the program is closer to the behaviour of the original code?

Comment: You can just do link[:href] or link['href'] instead of link.attr("href")

Comment: Perl's Mojolicious has a very similar interface, but that's not surprising since the author has a lot of Ruby experience. :)